# How/when to create trunk, branches and tags directories in a new subversion repository?

Tags: svn

When's the best time to create the trunk, branches and tags directories?

I have executed `svnadmin create --fs-type fsfs /home/firefli/web/projects/subversion` and have myself a blank repo. If I create, say, the `trunk` directory using `svn mkdir file:///home/firefli/web/projects/subversion/trunk` it works fine but I go to revision 1.

Not that going to revision 1 is a problem, I'm just sure I've done it differently before and I'm looking for the best practice.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When we create SVN repo's at work we `svnadmin create` and then `svn import` a skeleton folder of the 3 directories and commit that at once pushing it to revision 1 (We have a bash script automate all of this). I don't think there's a better practice than to just have the initial commit?

Comment: That's pretty much the same as we do - all automated with a script.

Answer (score 2):

You can create all directories at once (resulting in one commit) without even checking out the repo. See this Windows example:

```
svn mkdir -m "Creating basic directory structure" file:///d:/temp/repo/trunk file:///d:/temp/repo/tags file:///d:/temp/repo/branches
```

Answer (score 1):

On a fresh checkout of a new repository, I create and add the three directories - tags, trunk, and branches. I commit those three; the repo is on rev. 1, and I switch to trunk and get to work. Not much to it, really.